# 'X' is declared but its value is never read. Having trouble understanding where to assign it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

`Button.tsx`

```
import React from "react";

interface ButtonProps {
    name: string;
    onButtonClick: () => void;
}

function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
    const { name, onButtonClick } = props;

    function buttonAlert() {
        alert(`Testing`);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button className="buttonOne" onClick={buttonAlert}>{name}</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Button;
```

`index.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Button from './Button';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    <Button name="Button One" onButtonClick={() => { alert(`You clicked on Button One! `); }} />
    <Button name="Button Two" onButtonClick={() => { alert(`You clicked on Button Two! `); }} />
    <Button name="Button Three" onButtonClick={() => { alert(`You clicked on Button Three! `); }} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Okay so I am trying [9 Simple (But Important) React JS Coding Exercises You Need To Do As A Beginner](https://coderfiles.dev/blog/reactjs-coding-exercises/) and am currently on exercise three. I was asked to use TypeScript so I did add it to my project. I just had a meeting where I was told to use `onButtonClick` as a type and pass it as a prop in my `<Button />` component. Right now, what I do not understand and am having trouble figuring out is, where on earth do I pass the `onButtonClick` in my `Button.tsx` component. Which is why I am getting the message that I have declared it but I haven't used it. Could someone help me understand where exactly I am supposed to pass it?

Thank you!

Comment: Pass it to the `onClick` prop?

Comment: Instead of `onClick={buttonAlert}`, do `onClick={onButtonClick}` (at which point you can delete `buttonAlert`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you're not using the `onButtonClick` prop anywhere in your Button component. You have to use it instead of the hard-coded `buttonAlert` function that always shows the same message.

`Button.tsx`

```
import React from "react";

interface ButtonProps {
    name: string;
    onButtonClick: () => void;
}

function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
    const { name, onButtonClick } = props;

    /* Remove the hard-coded alert
    function buttonAlert() {
        alert(`Testing`);
    }*/

    /* Change buttonAlert on onClick to the onButtonClick prop */
    return (
        <div>
            <button className="buttonOne" onClick={onButtonClick}>{name}</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Button;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was putting onClick={onButtonClick}> but I did not remove the hard-coded alert function. I thought that was supposed to stay but it makes sense why it doesn't stay. I already had the alert function in the index.tsx file. Thanks!